# Fill in the day of the week according to the selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with one data column and another for the day of the week
When choosing a date I want the column to make the day filled with the name of the day according to a chosen data

I'm trying like this:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="date" class="data1" id="data1"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="data2" id="data2"/></td>';
    html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html); //<--- right here

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var semana = ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado"];
    $(".data1").on(function(){
        var data = this.value;
        var arr = data.split("-").reverse();
        var teste = new Date(arr[0], arr[1] - 1, arr[2]);
        var dia = teste.getDay();
        $(".data2").val();
    });
});
```

but does not show the alert when setting the date.
The date is in this form in the `input type = date`: 04-07-2019

**HTML:**

```
<div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
<table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Dia da Semana</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: couple of likely issues here, since you're adding your input elements dynamically when the "add" button is clicked:  1) you're duplicating ids - you can potentially add many items with "data1" as the ID. That's not valid in HTML. jQuery will not be able to tell them apart, or know which one you want to add a "blur" function to. 2) The input elements won't exist when you try to add the "blur" event handler, so the code won't find anything to attach the handler to. Google "jquery delegated events" to understand how to deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read ADyson comments above and therefor do some changes to your code. Some simple illustration would be:

```js
var daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

$('#add').click(function() {
    var html = '<tr>';
    html += '    <td><input type="date" class="input-date" /></td>';
    html += '    <td><input type="text" class="input-day" /></td>';
    html += '    <td><button type="button" class="button-insert">Insert</button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
});

$("body").on('change', '.input-date', function(e) {
    var thisDate = $(this);
    var data = thisDate.val();
    var teste = new Date(data);
    var dia = teste.getDay();
    var closestRow = thisDate.closest('tr');
    closestRow.find('.input-day').val(daysInWeek[dia]);
});

$("body").on('click', '.button-insert', function(e) {
    var thisButton = $(this);
    var closestRow = thisButton.closest('tr');
    /* Do whatever you want */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
</div>
<table id="user_data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Dia da Semana</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, no duplicate IDs and as second, [jQuery event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)...

Also on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afhq5j8m/1/).